# ¿Cómo clasificar URLs con Python?

Tags: python

Necesito de su ayuda quisiera crear un código para clasificar los diferentes tipos de URLs, ya sea en absolutas o relativas, he pensado en hacerlo con expresiones regulares pero lo veo muy ineficiente.

> http://www.wikipedia.org => url absoluta
>   wiki/url.html            => url relativa

Necesito crear algo que me clasifique de las forma anterior,  espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Si todas las urls relativas van a empezar por "http://<>" pues comprueba que la cadena que empieza así es absuluta, y si no relativa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay una excelente respuesta en el sitio en inglés que puedes verificar [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430167/regex-check-if-given-string-is-relative-url) y voy a traducirte, lo que se propone es usar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^(?!www\.|(?:http|ftp)s?://|[A-Za-z]:\\|//).*
```

Que básicamente verifica:

```
^                 # Desde el comienzo de la cadena
(?!               # Verificar que los próximos caracteres NO sean
www\.             # url que comienzan con www.
|                 # o
(?:http|ftp)s?:// # url que comienzan con http, https, ftp, ftps
|                 # o
[A-Za-z]:\\       # Carpetas locales del tipo [letra unidad]:\  
|
//                # o ubicaciones UNC que comienzan con //
)                 # Fin de grupo
.*                # Fin de la cadena
```

La solución podría ser así:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r"^(?!www\.|(?:http|ftp)s?://|[A-Za-z]:\\|//).*")

def url_type(url):
  return "realativa" if p.search(url) else "absoluta"

print(url_type("http://www.wikipedia.org"))
print(url_type("wiki/url.html"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando `urlparse` con Python 2:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('http://www.wikipedia.org').scheme
'http'
>>> urlparse('https://www.google.com').scheme
'https'
>>> urlparse('wiki/url.html').scheme
''
>>> urlparse('/bar/foo').scheme
''
```

Por lo tanto, podríamos decir, en cierta forma*, que las que no tienen un esquema (scheme) son relativas:

```
>>> urls = ['http://www.wikipedia.org', 'https://www.google.com', 'wiki/url.html', '/bar/foo']
>>> for url in urls:
...   if not urlparse(url).scheme:
...     print '"%s" -> Relativa' % url
...   else:
...     print '"%s" -> Absoluta' % url
... 
"http://www.wikipedia.org" -> Absoluta
"https://www.google.com" -> Absoluta
"wiki/url.html" -> Relativa
"/bar/foo" -> Relativa
```

---

*Lo digo en cierta forma ya que la siguiente URL podría considerarse como absoluta a pesar de no tener esquema:

```
www.google.com
```

Es una cuestión de interpretación. La [sintaxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) de una URL debe tener un esquema.